# Who is the leader of the pride troopers?

Tags: dragon-ball-series, dragon-ball-super

There are some spoilers for episode 101 of Dragon Ball Super which I believe comes from the Shonen Jump Magazine .

> Kahseral fights as well as you'd expect of the leader of the Pride Troopers

wasnt the leader of the Pride Troopers supposed to be Toppo? was this never mentioned in the anime?

Comment: I believe they had a talk in the anime where Toppo was talking with Kahseral and called him commander or something like that. So from there i assumed he was the leader

Comment: wasnt it lieutenant? I've heard a comment of him being called lieutenant, I personally dont remember it in the episodes

Comment: maybe, i'm not a japanese expert but to me it seemed he refered to him as an supperior. But i could be wrong here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The leader of the pride troopers is Toppo himself , it was confirmed in episode 82 , When toppo jumps down into the ring after Goku's fight with Bergamo . Toppo introduces himself as the leader of the Pride troopers of Universe 11 .

Another thing , Toppo refers to Kahseral as General , his second in command . The General in this context doesn't mean leader.

On Toppo and Kahseral , Taken from the Dragon Ball super wikia :

> Toppo suddenly jumps to the ring and confronts Goku, wanting to talk to him. He then introduces himself as the leader of the Pride Troopers of Universe 11

Later ,

> Some time after the fight, he decides to go to a bar, eating snacks with a concerned look in his eyes, realizing how much of his world's safety is at stake. His General, Kahseral, enters and asks why he is so upset.

Comment: Cool.That magazine must have it wrong or they misstranslated it.

Comment: Most probably , when they said expected they meant , he was fighting as good as toppo or something alike :)

Comment: Supposedly he's lieutenant or commander, so he has some grade of "leadership" in the group. But not over Toppo

Comment: Yes , I think the same as well.